# spring boot project define dependency class as spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I declared a service in package service like:

```
import a.b.c.d.soapapim.SoapApimMiddlewareService;

@Service
@EnableDefaultExceptionHandling
public class MyService{
    private final SoapApimMiddlewareService myService;

    public MyService(SoapApimMiddlewareService myService){
        this.myService = myService;   
    }

    public Response pullEvents(numEvents){
        myService.pullEvents(numEvents);
    }

}
```

SoapApimMiddlewareService is a dependency in my spring boot project declared in my project's pom.xml in the package a.b.c.d.soapapim

in my application.java:

```
@ComponentScan({"a.b.c.d.soapapim", "service", "scheduler"})
SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {´

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setRegisterShutdownHook(false);
        app.run(args);
    }

}
```

I also have a scheduler:

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {

    private MyService myService;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1200)
    public void myScheduledTask(){
        myService.pullEvents(1);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name MyService No qualifying bean of type 'a.b.c.d.soapapim.SoapApimMiddlewareService'

I can't annotate that class because its a dependency I don't have access to. I just declare it as a dependency on the pom.xml of my project.

How can I get this bean into the context of my spring boot application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it as spring bean using `@Bean` annotation in config class

```
@Bean
public SoapApimMiddlewareService soapApimMiddlewareService() {
    return new SoapApimMiddlewareService():
  }
```

Comment: in this case the SoapApimMiddlewreService has parameters do I need to declared them, instanciate and pass them on to it? I get the add parameters to match the declaration error

Comment: you are saying this class `SoapApimMiddlewareService` has parameter constructor? then yes you have to pass parameters @JoaoFilipeClementeMartins and it depends on what you need exactly

Comment: Ok this made me closer to solving the issue. But not in a class with @Config annotation. I had to put those in the Application class which contains SpringBootApplication annotation. do you know why?

Comment: you can put it in any class that is annotated with `@Configuraion`, `@Service` and `@Component` or even spring application class also, but keep it in mind these classes need to be under `@ComponentScan` package then only it will work